# Searching Directories "backwards" using windows API in C++

Tags: c++, windows, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the parent directory of the current folder in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233559/how-to-get-the-parent-directory-of-the-current-folder-in-a-c-program)

I am using the C++ Windows API and I look for folders and directories given a specific directory path initially (i.e. C:\...\ProjectXX). I use in particular the functions FindFirstFile() and FindNextFile(). I want however sometimes to move "backwards" in a directory, namely to get the "parent" of the given directory (the folder which contains the directory given). In what way is this possible and under the use of what functions?

Comment: Sounds more like upwards than backwards (Z->A).

Answer (score 0):

C++, unlike C, has a method for it: `.remove_leaf()`. But you're not using C++ functions, you're using WinAPI functions, so `PathRemoveFileSpec()` would be more fitting.